# Flex 4 -- Add new component at runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, components

I'm looking to make a "Generate component" button that will add a new component such as a Button to a Group. There could be any number of components added, so I don't want to use states. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var button:Button = new Button();
yourGroupId.addElement(button);
```